# Use position data of one geometry object on another

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am using Curve to Mesh to apply a profile along a circle. The profile curve is a line. I want to vary the length of the line according to e.g. the x coordinate within the circle. There are various vector math and math nodes that allow me to manipulate a 'position' input, but I do not know how to get the correct data flow. In the node setup shown in the picture, the 'position' input corresponds to whatever geometry I end up connecting it to, but a) I want to use the position data of one piece of geometry on another geometry, b) the input to 'curve line -> end' is not a field.

Any advice greatly appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what you want to achieve, but if you want this:

[image]

you can use this node setup:

[image]

Be aware: There is a big difference between circle sockets and diamond shaped sockets. The circle sockets are single value only. They are constant over one frame. The diamond sockets are fields (aka multiple values). So you cannot do it as you did want to do it. You have to change the position of the lines after instancing.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, it may be convenient to manipulate the *Radius* of the path curve, down which the profile is swept. That gives you a (XYZ) uniform scale of the profile, which can be varied as some function of the path:

[image]

Comment: nice one!! love it